# libtiff: TIFFGetField returns incorrect image' width and height

Tags: image-processing, tiff, codec, image-conversion, libtiff

I have a tiff file with 1736x1160x48b resolution. I'm using libtiff 4.0 dll and I have noticed that the resolution being read from the TIFFGetField function is incorrect. I'm getting 156 width and 104 height which is too low.

```
TIFF* pTiff;
pTiff = dll.OpenTIFF(szFilePath, (char*)("r"));
if (pTiff == nullptr) {
  return LPROCESS_FAILED;
}
uint32_t uWidth = 0;
uint32_t uHeight = 0;
int ret = 0;
ret = dll.TIFFGetField(pTiff, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &uWidth);
ret = dll.TIFFGetField(pTiff, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &uHeight );
// ret value is 1 on both lines
```

Do I need to update my tiff library to 4.5? Is there a fix on the latest version? or is this a format error on the image side? Though when I try to open the image on other photo viewing application, it was able to interpret correctly.

**Update:** I used libtiff 4.5 latest release and I'm still getting incorrect width and height. My guess is that the image I'm trying to load is not yet fully supported by libtiff. Here is the details of the image from exiftool:
[image]

Comment: Do the other photo viewing applications interpret the dimensions and bits correctly? And what is the content of the TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE field when you read the image with the library?

Comment: Run `exiftool YOURIMAGE.TIF` to get an accurate answer.

Comment: I have run exiftool and got the following: 
Image Width: 1736
Image Height: 1160
Bits Per Sample: 12

Comment: Please read [mre]. We can’t tell how you’re using this function because we haven’t seen variable declaration. How is `iWidth` declared? It has to have the right type for the field, otherwise you’ll get a wrong value out.

Comment: By the way, assuming LibTIFF is buggy rather than you using it wrong is rather arrogant. Millions of people use LibTIFF, if some version couldn’t read the image sizes right, it would have been pandemonium on the first day of release. Also, other tools you use to look at that TIFF file most likely also use LibTIFF.

Comment: IIRC, JPEG encoding and 12-bits/sample is notoriously problematic. Maybe you can convert your upstream processing to produce 16-bit/sample and LZW compression which is more widely supported.

Comment: Upon further checking, the tiff file must be a Canon Raw Format file saved as a tiff file. The one I'm reading is a small bmp file put by Canon while the extra data which is raw is lost

Comment: TIFF files often contain multiple copies of an image at different resolutions. If you run `exiftool` as I suggested, you'll likely find the full resolution image as the second one in your TIFF.

Comment: I was just going to say what @Mark just said. Try the `tiffinfo` tool that is installed with LibTIFF, it will show you each directory in the TIFF file and its properties.

Comment: So my problem now is how will I able to detect a tiff file is actually a raw file? is there some tag etc, that I can read?

Comment: Compare the output from `exiftool -v` from a raw file with a non-raw file and find a distinguishing characteristic.

Comment: So far, I'm reading the "Camera" field, if I read something then it's a camera raw format. I have encountered for Canon and Kodak images. Not that clean, but works though.